# Оптимизация SQL запроса

Tags: php, оптимизация, sql

Есть вот такой код:

```
for ($z=1; $z<=$ru; $z++) {
   $id['$z'] = $_SESSION['id'.$z];
   $idz = $id['$z'];
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT type FROM map WHERE id='$idz'"); 
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   if ($row['type'] == '0') {$row = 'ground';}
   if ($row['type'] == '1') {$row = 'tree';}
   if ($row['type'] == '2') {$row = 'water';}
   if ($row['type'] == '3') {$row = 'null';}
   if ($row['type'] == '4') {$row = 'dirt';}
   $_SESSION['type'.$z] = $row;
}
```

Он служит для отображения цвета координаты на такой вот штуке:
[image]

Как видите тут есть оси X и Y. Каждая координата имеет свой уникальный id (x:10 y:8 = id:100008 по формуле id=1000*x+y). При чем само поле имеет свой id по клеткам. То есть:
[image]

Так вот. Мы по id координаты делаем запрос к БД, в ответ получаем цифру (определенный цвет), далее цифру преобразовываем в текст который совпадает с названием class который применяем к div в каждой клетке (этот гемор я сделал потому что выяснил что работа с цифрами из БД проходит быстрее чем сразу со словами для подстановки в class). Далее в сессионную переменную записываем значение цвета, который и отображается.

**Вопрос:** как это чудо оптимизировать? все бы хорошо, но запрос для поля 30на30 проходит за чуть больше секунды, но 100на100 уже почти за 12(!). Без запросов к БД страница отображается в пределе 0.2 секунды. Понятно что грузит этот запрос в цикле, читал что так нельзя, но не нашел ничего как это исправить.

Comment: кэшируй просто

Comment: * а хранить карту как "битмап" не проще?
* выбирать все одним запросом, бежать по нему быстрее чем делать запросы в цикле.

Comment: Скрипт на создание таблицы в БД можно?
Если бы мы знали структуру таблицы, возможно нашли бы более правильный способ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

1. Сначала в массив `$mass` всеми возможными значениями `$idz`. -Это цикл.
2. Далее одним запросом (как я понял, поле `id` у Вас цифровое) вытягивает все данные с базы.

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT type FROM map WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $mass).")");`

СОгласен что нада Id
переделываем запрос

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, type FROM map WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $mass).")");
```

Оптимизируем дальше.

блок

```
switch ($row['type']) {
    case '0';
        $row = 'ground';
        break;
    case '1';
        $row = 'tree';
        break;
    case '2';
        $row = 'water';
        break;
    case '3';
        $row = 'null';
        break;
    case '4';
        $row = 'dirt';
        break;
}
```

Можно заменить таким образом:

```
//массив Типов

$type=array ('0'=>'ground', '1'=>'tree', '2'=>'water', '3'=>'null', '4'=>'dirt');

//в цикле только одна строка

$_SESSION['type'.$i] = $type[$row['type']];

//Таким образом получаем

///До этого момента берешь свой код

$type=array ('0'=>'ground', '1'=>'tree', '2'=>'water', '3'=>'null', '4'=>'dirt');
do{
 $_SESSION['type'.$i] = $type[$row['type']];
 $i++;
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Comment: Идею отказаться от циклического выполнения запросов - поддерживаю, но совать все id через запятую - считаю не самым лучшим решением, ибо их надо как-то вычислить.

Comment: ну так я и написал в п 1 - создаем массив из всех id)

Comment: судя по тому что id'шники идут подряд, то достаточно что-то типа

    where mod(id,1000) between $y and $y+100 
      AND floor(id/1000) between $x and $x+100

только это без индексов будет, тупиковая ветвь эволюции.

Comment: допустим в mass у нас id от 101 до 191.

$result = mysql_query("SELECT type FROM map WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $mass).")");

я понимаю что даст этот запрос, но как от сюда взять значение type для id=101 к примеру?

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за участие в обсуждении. Вопрос был решен таким образом:

```
for ($z=1; $z<=$ru; $z++) { //перечисляем количество клеток
$mass[$z] = $_SESSION['id'.$z]; //заносим в массив все id для запроса к БД
}
$massSql = implode(',', $mass); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,type FROM map WHERE id IN ($massSql)"); //сам запрос
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$i = 1;
//дальше смысл остался прежним
do {
switch ($row['type']) {
    case '0';
        $row = 'ground';
        break;
    case '1';
        $row = 'tree';
        break;
    case '2';
        $row = 'water';
        break;
    case '3';
        $row = 'null';
        break;
    case '4';
        $row = 'dirt';
        break;
}
$_SESSION['type'.$i] = $row;
$i++;
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

В итоге при прежней скорости для поля 100на100 в 12 секунд, имеем скорость в 0.2 секунды.

Comment: Для строки с $row['type'] switch сильно удлинняет код, юзайте массивы: array('ground', 'tree' ...), надеюсь, суть уловили.